# Python and C++ modulus

Tags: python, c++

I am learning c++ and in trying to code a little program i found something strange. It is about modulus :
c++ code

```
cout << -325 - (-325 % 100) << endl;
// -300 
cout << 325 - (325 % 100);
// 300
```

and python code

```
print(-325 - (-325 % 100))
# -400 
print(325 - (325 % 100))
# 300
```

Can someone explain me that pls ? Thq

Comment: [This multiplicative operator reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators) might help you understand what happens in C++. I suggest you try e.g. `-325 % 100` *separately* to see what it does. Pay close attention to the notes at the end of the section.

Comment: Different languages interpret the % operator differently. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit out of my expertise but its likely python follows the [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) remainder calculation which is: `a + b*[a/b]` being `[]` the [floor](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.floor) operation. As so:

```
a = -325
b = 100
print(a - b*math.floor(a/b))
print(math.floor(-3.25))
print(-325 -(a - b*math.floor(a/b)))
```

results in:

```
75
-4
-400
```

I'm a bit surprised C++ does not return the same (but I'm also not knowledgeable enough about the subject).

**EDIT:** Made a quick search for this topic and [learncpp](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/32-arithmetic-operators/) mentions the reason why C++, specifically C++ 11, standardized the floor operation always towards 0. I quote:

> Prior to C++11, if either of the operands of integer division are
>   negative, the compiler is free to round up or down! For example, -5 /
>   2 can evaluate to either -3 or -2, depending on which way the compiler
>   rounds. However, most modern compilers truncate towards 0 (so -5 / 2
>   would equal -2). The C++11 specification changed this to explicitly
>   define that integer division should always truncate towards 0 (or put
>   more simply, the fractional component is dropped).
>
> Also prior to C++11, if either operand of the modulus operator is
>   negative, the results of the modulus can be either negative or
>   positive! For example, -5 % 2 can evaluate to either 1 or -1. **The
>   C++11 specification tightens this up so that a % b always resolves to
>   the sign of a.**

Regarding Python you can take a look at the documentation for [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#divmod) which states:

> Take two (non complex) numbers as arguments and return a pair of
>   numbers consisting of their quotient and remainder when using integer
>   division. With mixed operand types, the rules for binary arithmetic
>   operators apply. For integers, the result is the same as (a // b, a %
>   b). For floating point numbers the result is (q, a % b), where q is
>   usually math.floor(a / b) but may be 1 less than that. In any case q *
>   b + a % b is very close to a, **if a % b is non-zero it has the same
>   sign as b**, and 0 <= abs(a % b) < abs(b)

**EDIT2:** Even more information on the [Python Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-22-10-return-3) regarding this subject.

> **Why does -22 // 10 return -3?**
>
> It’s primarily driven by the desire that
>   `i % j` have the same sign as `j`. If you want that, and also want:
>
> `i == (i // j) * j + (i % j)`
>
> then integer division has to return the
>   floor. C also requires that identity to hold, and then compilers that
>   truncate `i // j` need to make `i % j` have the same sign as `i`.
>
> There are few real use cases for `i % j` when `j` is negative. When `j` is
>   positive, there are many, and in virtually all of them it’s more
>   useful for `i % j` to be `>= 0`. If the clock says 10 now, what did it say
>   200 hours ago? `-190 % 12 == 2` is useful; `-190 % 12 == -10` is a bug
>   waiting to bite.

Comment: It gives the same result.

Comment: @verbalki Yeah, I found out why. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks phyton doesn't accept negative modulus results, so adds 100 to -25.

> print(-325 - (-325 % 100))

Comment: In Python, `a % b` always has the same sign as `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about it, but since you are learning C++,i would like to tell you something from my personal experience, that if you are making a program in C++ and you're using modulus operator, and you want +ve mod always, you should do something like this -

```
a = b%m;
if(a<0) a += m;
```

I am not so sure on when and why, but a can take a negative value for **any** b and m (not only when b is -ve)